# How to iterate a list of sobject returned from Apex controller in Lightning JS controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller

New to Lightning and trying to figure out how to process a list of sobject/custom metadata type records returned by Apex class in js controller before passing them to the component.

Apex Controller

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<HDS_Service_Setting__mdt> getServiceCategoryAndServicesByFundingType(string inputFundingTypeId) {
    system.debug('Dev Debug - Method Entered - FundingAndServicesController.getServiceCategoryAndServicesByFundingType()');
    string inputFundingTypeName = 'HCP';

    List<HDS_Service_Setting__mdt> lstServices = [SELECT Funding_Type__c,Service_Category__c,Service__c FROM HDS_Service_Setting__mdt WHERE Funding_Type__c=:inputFundingTypeName ];


    system.debug('Dev Debug - size of lstServices - '+lstServices.size());
    return lstServices;
}
```

JS Controller

```
var recordTypeId = component.get("v.recordTypeId");

    var action_getCategoryAndServiceByFundingType = component.get("c.getServiceCategoryAndServicesByFundingType");
    action_getCategoryAndServiceByFundingType.setParams({  inputFundingTypeId : recordTypeId  });
    action_getCategoryAndServiceByFundingType.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        var categoryAndService = a.getReturnValue();
        for(var thisRecord in categoryAndService)
            {
              alert(thisRecord.Service_Category__c);
            }


        component.set("v.CategoryAndService", categoryAndService);

        //var myJSON = JSON.stringify(categoryAndService); 
        //alert(myJSON);
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action_getCategoryAndServiceByFundingType);
```

What the alert gave me is undefined for each record.

Anyone can tell me how I can get the field value from each sObject record?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all (but maybe this is slightly overkill in this case) I would recommend to use wrapper inner class for sending data to the component. In your case it would be something like:

```
public class ServiceSettingWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled 
    String service {get; set;}
    public ServiceSettingWrapper(String service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Of course if Service__c is a string.
Then in your method you would need to create instance of this inner class add it ot a list and return.

```
List<HDS_Service_Setting__mdt> lstServices = [SELECT Funding_Type__c,Service_Category__c,Service__c FROM HDS_Service_Setting__mdt WHERE Funding_Type__c=:inputFundingTypeName ];

List<ServiceSettingWrapper> returnList = new List<ServiceSettingWrapper>();
for(HDS_Service_Setting_mdt setting : lstServices){
    returnList.add(new ServiceSettingWrapper(setting.Funding_Type__c,Service_Category__c,Service__c)
}

//In the end of methid
return returnList
```

Second thing:
Please check state of the response so you can handle eventual errors:

```
var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        //Actions for success
        } else if (state === "ERROR") {
          //Actions for error
        } else {
         //Another stuff
        }
```

And finally to your problem:

```
var listLength = categoryAndService.length;
for (var i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
    alert(categoryAndService[i]); -- which will return an object
    //or
    alert(categoryAndService[i].service); -- which wil lreturn specific field
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `for(var x in y)`; that causes you to iterate through the array's *keys*, which is not what you intended to do. Instead, simply use forEach:

```
categoryAndService.forEach(record => console.log(record.Service_Category__c));
```

Note that JavaScript is also case sensitive, so you might need to check the capitalization of the field.

Comment: You can also just be sure to use the key the way it is intended like `categoryAndService[thisRecord].Service_Category__c`. Although according to this benchmark site, `forEach` is the winner winner chicken dinner. https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/1037/0/for-vs-foreach-vs-some